# Save Zoho Creator form in crm and in mysql database

Tags: zoho

I like to create a registration form and not only store part of it in Zoho CRM but also I like to save the data in my MySQl database on my server.

for example in the registration form the user should enter a username and password. I like to put this in the database, but the name etc. should be in Zoho CRM.

How can I do it? I thought maybe with Curl or so. Is that right?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The better and easy way to post Form data to two different servers is to use a Zoho Creator Form. Zoho Creator offers a deluge task that push data to Zoho CRM and there exists a postUrl task to push data to any HTTP server. Refer to the below links for details.

1. https://forums.zoho.com/topic/push-data-to-zoho-crm
2. https://www.zoho.com/creator/help/script/post-url.html